# JSONArray putting the data with extra escape

Tags: java, json, rest

I am using code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(1, "ADMIN");
jsonArray.put(2, "DATA");
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("slice_roles", jsonArray);
jsonObj.put("admin_slice", "10.143.229.238");
jsonObj.put("slice_address", "10.143.229.238");
String requestJson = jsonObj.toString();
```

The output requestJson I am getting is:

```
[{"slice_roles":[\"ADMIN\",\"UI\"],"admin_slice":"10.143.229.238","slice_address":"10.143.229.238"}]
```

I want to get:

```
[{"slice_roles":["ADMIN","UI"],"admin_slice":"10.143.229.238","slice_address":"10.143.229.238"}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suspect there is something going on you're not telling us -- other operations intermingled there.

Comment: I am making a REST call after this. And these code are under execute method, which is called by an ant target.

Comment: I mean with regard to the construction of the JSONArray.  The above error it too egregious to be the result of any commonly used JSON kit.  And I note that the JSON you list could not have possibly come from the above code, since the JSON is "wrapped" with an "array", while your outermost entity is an "object".  You need to show us the *real* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which JSON library are you using? After using several, I've settled on [FastJSON](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson) which has the biggest benefits of implementing `List` and `Map` for `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` respectively, and I expect it will solve your issue too.

Comment: Worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update based on @HotLicks comment:**

Your JSON is not valid since the double quotes are not always escaped in your String. May be you should check the way and library which creates the JSON.

Comment: My output should look like ["ADMIN","UI"] not [\"ADMIN\",\"UI\"]

Comment: if you do that, then the String will end after `[`. i.e. first double quote

Comment: It's not clear that this is the case.  The other quotes in the string are not escaped.

Comment: If the backslash characters remain, the following quote characters would be treated as plain old characters rather than "enclosing" quotes, and the effect would be the same as not having quotes at all (ie, invalid JSON).

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, you are right. I missed it. I will update my answer though